# What is the "e" in myFunc(e) and how can I pass other parameters to myFunc?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [In Javascript/jQuery what does (e) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323392/in-javascript-jquery-what-does-e-mean)
>
> [jQuery's .click - pass parameters to user function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)

Given this code:

```
function myFunc(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

var x = 99;
$('#myId').bind('click', myFunc);
```

Can someone tell me what is the e parameter. Also how could I pass the x parameter to myFunc ?

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: As there is no mention of data (x) in the linked "duplicate", I don't think this is a proper duplicate.

Comment: Given that specific code, you would have no reason to pass `x`. You'd just have `myFunc` do a direct reference. Of course your actual code may be different.

Comment: @dystroy This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323392/in-javascript-jquery-what-does-e-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the click event, wrapped as a jquery event.

If you want to pass x, you may do this :

```
$('#myId').bind('click', {x:x}, myFunc);
```

Your function will find `x` in `e.data.x`.

If you need the native event (i.e. not the jQuery one), use `e.originalEvent` but many fields of the event are accessible through `e`.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: thanks. glad to see your answer before the question was closed.

Comment: The question wasn't clear on this point, but it should be noted that the handler won't get `x` via event data. It'll get `99` with every invocation irrespective of the current value of `x`. To provide the current value, OP would need to wrap `myFunc` in another function that has direct access, and pass along the current value. All this of course assumes that `myFunc` is out of scope of `x`. If not, then obviously `myFunc` should just reference it directly.